# How to update window after each iteration of a loop in js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

I'm trying to update the window after each iteration of the loop.  The code in question is below. After picking the initial live cells I press next which should iterate through the loop. It reaches the correct final state, but does not display the states in-between.

Plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/Gtp87m48YT5wGbSytQX4?p=preview

I understand that I probably have to use setInterval, but whenever I try implementing it, it just freezes the window or skips to the end. I've tried using the angular $interval, but I have the same problem

```
$scope.next = function newgrid() {
        var num=3;

        while(num>0)
        {
        $scope.history.push($scope.board);
        $scope.board = computeNext($scope.board);
        num--;
        }

    };
```

Edit updated code. Now it just stays stuck on the initial state:

```
$scope.next = function newgrid() {


        $interval(function() {
           $scope.history.push($scope.board);
           $scope.board = computeNext($scope.board);
      }, 1000);    
    };
```

Comment: This loop will execute so fast you won't see anything until the last value.  You need `$interval` to delay a bit before you can see anything changing.

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I do the window doesn't respond. It just stays on the initial state. My updated code is above.